# Why is a non-rechargeable cell a "primary" cell, and a rechargeable cell "secondary"

Tags: batteries, terminology

I was relating [the Digi-Key Trivia Thursday question](https://twitter.com/digikey/status/459406777873100800) to my friend today and he was confused why a rechargeable cell is "secondary", and all I could reply with is "it just is".  The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rechargeable_battery) for rechargeable batteries only mentions:

> It is technically known as a **secondary cell** because its electrochemical reactions are electrically reversible.

That connection still seems totally arbitrary; I can't find anything about "secondary electrochemical reactions" or "secondary redox". What is the connection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A primary cell is a "prime mover" in old fashioned terms; namely a source of power in its own right until its chemistry is exhausted. That power was not "put into it" e.g. by charging but was inherent in the materials used in it, the same way that wood or coal are a source of heat.

A secondary cell is *not* (usually) a source of power in its own right : it is a store of power *originally generated somewhere else*.

I would agree that the distinction is somewhat artificial and you could conceive of a cell which produced power *once* as a primary cell when first assembled, then be recharged from another power source and operate as a secondary cell. But I don't know of any such cells in practice.

(Likewise you can argue that wood is merely an inefficient store of solar energy rather than a "prime mover" and modern forestry is just a closed-loop process!)

Comment: I believe it is possible to recharge (some?) alkaline cells, so you could claim they are primary cells that can be used as secondary (but they make poor secondary cells, if I recall correctly).